# Uniform and pointwise convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n+n}{1+n^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If I consider $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{1+n^2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{1+n^2}$$
I have that the first series converges in all $\mathbb R$ and the second diverges so the given series diverges?

If $|x|\le1$ the general term $f_n(x) \sim_{+\infty} {{1}\over{n}}$ general term of a divergent series

If $|x|>1$ the general term $f_n(x) \sim_{+\infty}{{x^n}\over{1+n^2}}$ general term of a power series that diverges.
So the given series diverges?

Comment: The first series is a power series and the radius of convergence is $+\infty$ ?

Comment: The 1st series does *not* converge over all of $\mathbb R$, in particular it diverges for $|x|>1$. When they both diverge you *can not* conclude that the original series diverges from that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ diverges, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(a_n+b_n)$ always diverges.

Answer (score 1):

> I have that the first series converges in all $\mathbb  R$

The series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{1+n^2}$$ diverges for $|x| > 1$.  Simply because the addends do not converge to 0.

Comment: I have edited the solution.It's correct?